# Order by text and number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a text column in my DB that stores a list of house names and numbers and when i order by ASC it outputs like this:

```
"Name No 1"
"Name No 12"
"Name No 14"
"Name No 5"
"Name No 7"
```

Is there an easy way of ordering it in the actual order like:

```
"Name No 1"
"Name No 5"
"Name no 7"
"Name No 12"
"Name No 14"
```

If it was my site i would have had two columns one for name, and another for number but i cannot change it as it's a live site

Comment: I would highly recommend to use 2 seperate columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ORDER BY LENGTH(colname) ASC, colname ASC`

This is probably as close as you're going to get to a "proper order".

Comment: Very clever! This is a pretty elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    col1
FROM 
    Table1
ORDER BY 
    LENGTH(col1), col1
```

Answer (score 0):

Does house name column in your table follows the same pattern? 
If so you can use **SUBSTRING** function

```
SELECT house_name FROM  houseTbl order by convert((substr(house_name ,9),unsigned);
```